# Ubuntu 14.04 and MTP/Android (Samsung s3 mini)

Tags: android, samsung, mtp

I have some issues with MTP/Android on my Ubuntu 14.04. When I connect the cell phone to the Laptop (HP ZBook 17) it will be recognized by the system as well (sometimes I have to reconnect the cell phone, but does not matter) and even I can "explore" its content in Thunar (I have installed the Xubuntu-  XFCE4 - GUI) I cannot play the music stored in it.
I can navigate into the Phone/Card without problem, but when I double click on a mp3, the file is not played in the player. I have tried all I found on the internet, but nothing helped. I installed also VLC, Amarok and other "mtp-players" but also this did not helped.
With VLC as I tried to open a mp3 file from the cell it caught an error "could not play the file at /run/user/1000/mpt...." --> the mountpoint of the GVFS.
With Amarok I could see some files but also I couldn't be able to play them.

I have read somewhere on the internet, that the MTP under Ubuntu is only supported for upload/download! So is this real? I cannot play my music from the datei manager without first copying the file to the harddisk? As I do in MS-Windows? Is this function planned to be fully supported by Ubuntu?

Many thanks

ale974